# How reliable is contenteditable for simple digit editing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, html-table

We have a site where users can enter statistics for an item.
The statistics are simply int's or float's no formatting required.

We could set it up so that each `td` gets replaced with a `<input type="text" />`, but that requires us formatting the inputs so they look like they aren't inputs, and that comes with a whole host of cross browser css problems!

So we are looking at `contenteditable`, But I am wondering how many issues we are likely to run into with this?

We are looking at using an implementation basically like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hailwood/XQhh3/

Comment: Keep in mind that contenteditable is poorly supported around browsers. Styling an input would be a lot more easier.

Comment: What part's of it are poorly supported? All modern browsers (and even IE back to version 6!) support it, they all have slightly different implementations for it, but that tends to relate to the rich text editing, which I am not concerned about, inputs on the other hand are styled different in every browser, and that would need to be accounted for!

Comment: Yes, but it requires JS, and not all mobiles support it. I would rather vote for might look ugly than might not work at all... Because even if the inputs are not perfectly styled, at least the users can use them.

Comment: If we are not concerned about mobile browsers? (the site in general wouldn't work from mobile browsers as it requires things like uploading 100mb+ files, along with the design not being err mobile friendly), also, we will be using ajax regardless of inputs or contenteditable, so JS is required either way.

Comment: then go with contenteditable. Just make sure to not allow html, since you are expecting numbers only I suggest you block any other character to make sure the user interferes with your html. This is usually circumvented by using IFRAME but you won't need that.

Comment: Yeah, if you check the demo I posted I am pretty sure I stop any other possibility of anything but numbers.

Comment: You can't stop anything from happening client side. Ever.

Comment: It's a given that you re-validate on the server side, but you still try to prevent it on the client side to prevent accidents....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many HTML rich text editors that use this approach, and your problem appears considerably simpler. If you are only worried about client side issues, compatibility is the biggest problem I can think of. [Many](http://caniuse.com/contenteditable) mobile browsers do not support this.

Most of the difficulties I can see you running into pertain to DOM selection and manipulation if you have more complex content than text nodes, but otherwise you should be fine.